# Drop Down List and one formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to get an average depending on two drop down lists. 
But i would like to get an average even when the second drop down has no input in it.

The formula I use is a simple: `AVERAGEIFS` with: average range depending on the number column, 1st drop down list range and the drop down list cell as a criteria1 and the same for the second one.

Unfortunately I get an error outcome when there is no data selected in  the second drop down list.

How can i modify the formula?  Here is a picture of what i have.

[image: Here is a picture of what i have]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some `IF`s to make it working:

`=IF(A3="",IF(B3="",AVERAGE(D7:D12),AVERAGEIF(D7:D12,type,B3)),IF(B3="",AVERAGEIF(D7:D12,taille,A3),AVERAGEIFS(D7:D12,taille,A3,type,B3)))`

Answer (score 0):

I used this formula in the end and it worked. I dont know why yours was still giving me an error.

Thank you for your help

> =IF(B3="",AVERAGEIF(taille,A3,D7:D12),IF(A3="",AVERAGEIF(type,B3,D7:D12),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(D7:D12,taille,A3,type,B3),"No Combo")))